# Vim doesn't indent when inserting carriage return from a function?

Tags: vim

So I'm trying to write a function that makes inserting semi colons a bit more pleasant:

```
        inoremap <leader>; <esc>:call InsertSemiColin()<cr>
```

Basically it checks to see if I'm standing at the end of the current line, if so I auto-format the code, insert the semi-colon at the end and break down to the next line (carriage return)

```
fun! InsertSemiColin()
    if (!IsEOL()) | exec "normal! a;" | return | endif
    exec "normal! \<esc>:OmniSharpCodeFormat\<cr>A;\<cr>"
endf:

fun! IsEOL()
    " col number == length of current line?
    return col('.') == strlen(getline(line('.'))) " or just getline('.')
endf
```

Expectation:

[image]

Result:

[image]

To try it out on your own, you can remove the code-formatting and just do:

```
    exec "normal! a;\<cr>"
```

My indentation settings:

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
filetype plugin indent on
```

The weird thing is that if I don't insert the carriage return from a function, it works as expected!

```
inoremap <leader>; ;<cr>
```

Why is this happening? and how can I get the result I'm expecting?

Very frustrating, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid leaving and re-entering insert mode for this via `:help :map-expr`:

```
inoremap <expr> <leader>; ';' . (IsEOL() ? '<esc>:OmniSharpCodeFormat<cr>A<cr>' : '')
```

For this to work, you need to change the comparison in the `IsEOL()` function:

```
fun! IsEOL()
    " col number == length of current line?
    return col('.') > strlen(getline(line('.'))) " or just getline('.')
endf
```

This also fixes the indent problem.

Comment: Thanks that works. But I'm not sure now where/how to insert the call to format code without leaving and re-entering insert mode...

Comment: Oh, I removed that (because I don't have that command). You should be able to insert that; see my edit.

Comment: That does it. I will accept your answer. However; I'd like to understand why it doesn't work when using a function - I'm lucky here cause there isn't much code involved for me to inline it like that, but in the future there might be...

Comment: I first thought it's because of `inoremap` (vs. `imap`), as this affects abbreviation expansion etc., but it wasn't. I don't know; you may have to delve into the source code to find the reason. It may even be a bug.